# WPF MVVM - Bind to a property from an ancestor view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, relativesource

I have a nest of views/view models similar to the following:

```
CustomDialogView
  CustomView
    CustomListView
      CustomControl
        -SomeCustomProperty
```

Each of these views is bound to an appropriate view model.

I'm trying to bind SomeCustomProperty to a property on CustomDialogView's view model.

What is the best way to do this? I have tried a few things, the most promising of which seemed to be setting the binding of this property through RelativeSource FindAncestor like:

```
<CustomControl
    SomeCustomProperty="{
        Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
        AncestorType={x:Type sourcePath:CustomDialogViewModel}},
        Path=SomeCustomProperty,
        Mode=OneWay/>
</CustomControl>
```

But I'm getting no binding here at all.

I'm not sure if it has any bearing but the CustomListView is populated by a factory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FindAncestor` is finding a View not the bound ViewModel. Due to that fact you need to set the type of the View as `AncestorType`. Now you are able to access the ViewModel of this View by adding `DataContext` to the `Path` to bind.

```
<CustomControl
    SomeCustomProperty="{
        Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
        AncestorType={x:Type sourcePath:CustomDialogView}},
        Path=DataContext.SomeCustomProperty,
        Mode=OneWay/>
</CustomControl>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you :)